# Showing and hiding sections of HTML

Tags: html, css

I would essentially like to be able to show and hide sections of HTML with a click of a button.

It is a bit hard to explain but I have a fiddle so show what I mean. As it stands I can only make one and I need to be able to create multiple. The code is done with inline css because I have no access to the stylesheet where this is to be used.

https://jsfiddle.net/edbaz1qd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If you want to hide something you can apply `display: none`. If you want to do it on click you need some js.

Comment: Would you be open to learning how to place javascript event handlers on html elements?  Check this out:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Comment: @Takendarkk Essentially if you see the fiddle, you can click 'read more' and the section is opened up. I would like to do that inside the section that opens up as well.

Comment: @JoeEssey It's easier to do stuff with JS but I cannot use it where I want to use this bit of code. The only thing I can use is HTML and inline css.

Comment: @TheLimeTrees pls have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but this is a handy piece of code that i use for showing/hiding text

```css
html {
  background: white
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
figure {
  margin: 0 0 1.3rem 0;
  -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
  -moz-transition: .125s linear;
  -ms-transition: .125s linear;
  -o-transition: .125s linear;
  transition: .125s linear;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
body {
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 3em auto;
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
}
body:before,
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
body:after {
  clear: both
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1.3rem
}
article {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
}
article:before,
article:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
article:after {
  clear: both
}
article figure {
  float: left;
  width: 32.5%;
}
article section:first-of-type {
  float: right;
  width: 62.5%;
}
article section:last-of-type {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
section {
  -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
  -moz-transition: .125s linear;
  -ms-transition: .125s linear;
  -o-transition: .125s linear;
  transition: .125s linear;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
[for="read_more"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .65rem;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
[for="read_more"]:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
[for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ section {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ figure {
  width: 100%
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:first-of-type {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Show/hide</title>
</head>

<body>
  <article>


    <input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
    <label for="read_more" onclick=""><span>Show</span><span>Hide</span>
    </label>

    <figure>
      <img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg" alt="Picture" />
    </figure>

    <section>
      <p>Short Intro goes here. Write whatever you like.</p>
    </section>



    <section>
      <p>Full article goes here. We'll make do with lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu orci elit. Pellentesque vel risus tortor. Pellentesque ut diam mi. Nunc iaculis ante ac tempus scelerisque. Etiam vestibulum
        elementum quam et interdum. Integer vitae augue vitae nunc pulvinar scelerisque eu vitae justo. Mauris urna erat, ornare ut eros non, varius bibendum mauris. Vivamus dolor felis, tincidunt sed malesuada vel, ornare non ligula. Curabitur blandit
        massa vitae ullamcorper fermentum. Nam rutrum odio dui, vitae tempus dui maximus sed.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu orci elit. Pellentesque vel risus tortor. Pellentesque ut diam mi. Nunc iaculis ante ac tempus scelerisque. Etiam vestibulum elementum quam et interdum. Integer vitae augue vitae
        nunc pulvinar scelerisque eu vitae justo. Mauris urna erat, ornare ut eros non, varius bibendum mauris. Vivamus dolor felis, tincidunt sed malesuada vel, ornare non ligula. Curabitur blandit massa vitae ullamcorper fermentum. Nam rutrum odio dui,
        vitae tempus dui maximus sed.</p>

    </section>

  </article>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you have understood what I want, thanks for the assist. Only thing is here the other bottom article doesn't open. The show hide is only linked to the first one.

Comment: you can fiddle with the css to make multiple show/hides tho, how about an upvote?

Comment: Haha, there you go! I've tried that before but I was having a lot of problems with making it work which was why I hopped on here

Comment: @TheLimeTrees thanks :) someone unaccepted an answer of mine today i  was v unimmpressed

Comment: @TheLimeTrees hey for multiple elements check this out it's javascript http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/ neat! now do i get an accept??? :)